In Plotly parallel coordinates, change order of line traces in each category in
The following figure is generated using Plotly parallel categories. The lines connecting to each category are stacked with respect to the corresponding accuracy value in an ascending order, so that red lines are placed at the bottom and blue ones at the top. How can I change the order (z-order???) of lines connecting to cells/categories?
Here is the code snippet that generates this figure.
# Create dimensions
Ra = go.parcats.Dimension(
    values=df.param_reach_a, label='R(a)',
    categoryorder='category descending', 
)

Rr = go.parcats.Dimension(
    values=df.param_reach_r, label='R(r)',
    categoryorder='category descending', 
)

# map metric_col bins to the correspond accuracy values, used for tick labels
df['metric_col_mapped'] = df.metric_col_binned.map({i: f'{bins[i]*100:.2f} - {bins[i+1]*100:.2f}' for i in range(len(bins)-1)})

accuracy_bins = go.parcats.Dimension(
    values=df.metric_col_mapped, 
    label='Accuracy Bins',
    # label='<i>R</i><sup>(<i>a</i>)</sup>',
    categoryorder='category descending', 
    # categoryarray=list(df.metric_col_binned.unique()),
    categoryarray=[f'{bins[i]:.2f} - {bins[i+1]:.2f}' for i in range(len(bins)-1)],
    ticktext=[f'{bins[i]:.2f} - {bins[i+1]:.2f}' for i in range(len(bins)-1)]
)

dimensions = [Ra, Rr, accuracy_bins]
if(include_landmark_ratios):
    # Create a dimension for 'param_landmarks_ratio'
    landmark_ratio_dim = go.parcats.Dimension(
        values=df.param_landmarks_ratio, label='Landmark Nodes Ratio',
        categoryorder='category descending',
    )
    dimensions.insert(2, landmark_ratio_dim)

color = df[metric_col_binned]
fig = go.Figure(
    data = [go.Parcats(dimensions=dimensions,
                line={
                    'color': color, 
                    'colorscale': colorscale, 
                    'shape': 'hspline', # for curved lines at nodes
                    },
                hoveron='color', hoverinfo='count+probability',
                labelfont={'size': 18, 'family': 'Times'},
                tickfont={'size': 16, },
                arrangement='freeform',
                )
            ],
    )


